# Salesforce - Insert data to a multipicklist using PHP API Call

Tags: php, api, salesforce

I am new to SalesForce. I am trying to create a new "Account" object in SalesForce using PHP API call.

This works perfectly when I am not passing values to the multipicklist. When I pass data to the multipicklist field it throws me an error.

This is the error message I am getting.

> SFDC ERROR : bad value for restricted picklist field: Oracle bad value for restricted picklist field: Microsoft bad value for restricted picklist field: Mambu bad value for restricted picklist field: Comply Advantage

> ERROR Code :- INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST

The values saved in my database are semicolon separated. **Oracle;Microsoft;Mambu;Comply Advantage**

This is my array that I am passing over to SFDC.

```
$content = [
    'Name' => 'My Account Name', // this the account name
    'partnerships' => 'Oracle;Microsoft;Mambu;Comply Advantage'
];
```

This is the field value list.

[image]

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix this error. Thank You.

Comment: Does your partnerships picklist in Salesforce have all your options defined for it?

Comment: Yes, the options in the image are the option defined. Nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your Salesforce admin check if company is using "record types" on Account object. They're like "ok, it's a company, they will all sit in one database table but I need to display different fieldsbwhether it's factory, office, hospital or what. And they'll have different logic too, not all fields mandatory for hospital..."

If you don't explicitly set record type there might be a default one assigned to your user Profile anyway. Admin could then go to this recordtype's page and check the picklist. That in theory these 12 values are available at all for Accounts doesn't mean that this particular record type can use all of them. Like I don't know, if company is in Europe you can't ever offer free shipping, something like that.

[image]